# Function doesn't return variable when reassigning it a 2nd time

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I've created two Functions:
First Function is createGrid(N) which creates a NxN-matrix with '-' as placeholders and two points 'b' and 'p' which are randomly created. This function returns the Grid, and the coordinates in b and p. All works fine here.

In the 2nd Function I want to move 'b' Up, Left, Down or Right and return the  matrix with the new coordinate of b. But b isn't returned here.

I've already tried to use global variables and c = copy.copy(b) with returning c.
Those both didn't work.

1st Function

```
import numpy as np
def createGrid(N):
    board = np.full((N,N),'-')
    #position p
    p = np.random.randint(low=0, high = N, size=([1,2]))
    #position b
    b = np.random.randint(low=0, high = N, size=([1,2]))
    #insert 'p' and 'b' in board
    board[p[0,0],p[0,1]] = 'p'
    board[b[0,0],b[0,1]] = 'b'
    return board, p, b
```

createGrid(5)
print(board)

```
[['-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' 'b' '-']
 ['-' '-' 'p' '-' '-']]
```

print(b)

```
[[3 3]]
```

2nd Function

```
def nextMove(move,b,board):
    if move == 'Up':
       board[b[0,0],b[0,1]] = '-'
       b = np.array([[b[0,0]-1,b[0,1]]])
       board[b[0,0],b[0,1]] = 'b'
       return board, b
```

nextMove('Up',b,board)
print(board

```
[['-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' 'b' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' 'p' '-' '-']]
```

print(b)

```
[[3 3]]
```

b isn't returned by the 2nd function at all. Strangely the matrix with the new position is returned though.

I've another small question: How can the 2nd Function find the parameters b and board by itself without me passing it?

Comment: You don't even use the return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b = np.array([[b[0,0]-1,b[0,1]]])` does not update the `b` variable in the outer scope but `board[b[0,0],b[0,1]] = '-'` does update the data in `board`. You can read up the basics about passing arguments in python here: https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php

This fixes your problem:

```
board, b = nextMove('Up', b, board)
print(board)
print(b)
```

You already return `board` and `b` from your `nextMove` function, you just need to assign these return values